# Setting Solver within VBA for a UDF with internal references

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, solver

I am trying to create a function which essentially is equivalent to a variable that needs to be changed in Excel Solver in order to obtain solve equality or inequality. Since it goes through a variable number of iterations, I do not wish to record every FOR loop output and do the solver with a macro or cell references. Here is some sample data:

```
Clean_Price =  30,343,540
Number_of_Payments = 4
Coupon = 2.80%
Face = 30,000,000
Zero_Curve = [-0.35%   -0.28%   -0.14%   0.02%] (starting at index 1 for the code)
```

---

```
Function ZS(Clean_Price As Variant, Number_of_Payments As Integer, Coupon As Variant, Face As Variant, AccIn As Variant, Zero_Curve As Range)

    Dim Payment() As Variant                     'Periodic Payments
    ReDim Payment(0 To Number_of_Payments) As Variant

    Dim Disc() As Variant                        'Discount rate
    ReDim Disc(0 To Number_of_Payments) As Variant

    Dim SP As Variant                            'Sumproduct of payments and discount rates

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Number_of_Payments

        Select Case i
        Case 0
            Payment(i) = AccIn
            Disc(i) = 1 / (1 + Zero_Curve(i) + ZS) ^ i

        Case Number_of_Payments - 1
            Payment(i) = (AccIn / Coupon) + (Coupon * Face)
            Disc(i) = 1 / (1 + Zero_Curve(i) + ZS) ^ i

        Case Number_of_Payments
            Payment(i) = ((Coupon * Face) - (AccIn)) + (((Coupon * Face) - (AccIn)) / Coupon)
            Disc(i) = 1 / (1 + Zero_Curve(i) + ZS) ^ i

        Case Else
            Payment(i) = Coupon * Face
            Disc(i) = 1 / (1 + Zero_Curve(i) + ZS) ^ i

        End Select
    Next i

    'Solver statements
    SP = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(Payment(), Disc())
    'ZS such that SP/(Clean_Price+AccIn) = 1

End Function
```

Comment: OK, you have created a function. Is it working? Is it doing what you expect? Do you have a question here? Or are you expecting someone to write random code for you?

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding, AJD. The system seems to have edited my question, removing the question part. What I need to know is whether I can use the solver function with internal references from my VBA. That is, instead of referring to cells in the worksheet, would it be possible to use values from my loop in the condition shown above to isolate ZS.